# Композиция двух классов

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Тема: Композиция двух классов. Вложенный класс.

Задача:

Реализовать два способа задания вспомогательного класса:

Проект 1. Вспомогательный класс должен быть определен как независимый.

Проект 2. Вспомогательный класс должен быть определен как вложенный и закрытый.

Под первым подразумевается это?

```
class A{
...
}

class B{
private:
A object;
}
```

Если да, то что от меня требуют во втором проекте? Если нет, то покажите как правильно сделать обе. Приведите самый простой пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Под первым подразумевается это?

Да.

> Проект 2. Вспомогательный класс должен быть определен как вложенный и закрытый.
>   ...что от меня требуют во втором проекте?

Видимо что-то вроде

```
class B
{
  private:
    class A {...};
    A object;
};
```